# Should I create a separate Realm object for custom grouping?

Tags: swift, realm

I have been using Realm in an app and love it. Thank you! I have a question I would like to run by you folks and get some advice.

Lets say you have a realm object that contains a date field (simplified example):

```
class Appointment: Object {

    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var date = Date()
}
```

Now, suppose you have saved thousands of Appointments, and you are going to display these on a tableview or collectionview, grouped by week for example. So the datasource for your view would be something like this.

```
struct AppointmentsInWeek {
    var startDate: Date?
    var endDate: Date?
    var appointments: [Appointment]
}
```

So, I have two options in mind I am thinking through with various pros and cons:
 
**A)** Make `AppointmentsInWeek` a subclass of `Object`, save it in the Realm, and use that as the datasource.

PROS:

- Data for table will be lazy loaded from Realm
- Simple to use at the moment it is needed.

CONS:

- Keeping this up to date seems like a challenge. I would probably have some kind of observable looking at the `Appointment` in Realm and as any are added put them in the appropriate `AppointmentWeek`

**B)** Upon loading the screen with the tableview, fetch all appointments, or a subset of them, group them by their appropriate start and end date, and create an `AppointmentsInWeek` struct to use as the datasource.

PROS:

- `AppointmentsInWeek` will always be up to date because it is created on the fly as needed

CONS:

- We would have to keep all of this in memory, limiting the amount of appointments we could realistically display at once.

I started with **option B** but I am thinking now it might be better to go with **option A**. If I do, the biggest issue is making sure the Realm is always up to date when new appointments are added.

#### Questions

1. Are there other options I did not consider?
2. Which sounds like a better option?
3. Assuming I go with option A, would it make sense to have a class, that lives throughout the life of the app, in charge of observing the `Appointments` in Realm and when one is added (or changed), add it also to the appropriate `AppointmentWeek`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are fine, but I suggest option A. There are a few ways to approach option A.

First of all, you don't need to keep `Appointment` and `AppointmentsInWeek` in sync manually. You can use some combination of [object properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-one-relationships), [list properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships), and [linking objects properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) to model connections between `Appointment`s and `AppointmentsInWeek`s. Exactly how you might implement this depends on your app's specific needs, but here's one possibility:

```
class Appointment : Object {
    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    // Link to the week this appointment lives in, if desired
    var week: AppointmentsInWeek? = nil
}

class AppointmentsInWeek : Object {
    dynamic var startDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var endDate = NSDate()
    // Add appointment to List whenever it's created
    let appointments = List<Appointment>()
}
```

A second possibility is to not use relationships at all, but to use queries instead. Realm supports queries through the [`Results`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) class. You could add an ignored property on your `AppointmentsInWeek` class that queries the Realm for all appointments that fall within its date range:

```
class Appointment : Object {
    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
}

class AppointmentsInWeek : Object {
    dynamic var startDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var endDate = NSDate()

    lazy var appointments: Results<Appointment> = {
        // This implementation assumes you can get a reference
        // to the Realm storing your Appointments somehow
        return appointmentsRealm.objects(Appointments.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", self.startDate, self.endDate))
    }()

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["appointments"]
    }
}
```

In either case Realms, lists, and results all update automatically whenever the runloop of the thread they are on (usually the main thread) runs. Realm also supports a variety of [notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) in case you need to react to changes manually.

Comment: Thank you for pointing these options out. I actually had not heard of the linkingObject property before (missed it when reading the docs somehow).